# Twilio iOS client unlisten or capability token expiration causes crash

Tags: ios, twilio

According to twilio this issue was fixed. As stated in their changelog:

`MSDK-100 - Corrected a crash that could occasionally occur when un-registering a TCDevice by calling -unlisten or due to capability token expiration.`

However it keeps crashing for me regardless.

Thread log can be found [here](https://p5assets.zendesk.com/attachment/QO4IJrtBYwMJP2I84X9EtQ?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..TsdQWkM8LG-SIPLcf_YFMg.v8QrS6KwLfYof8X6l2OY8S6dQZRqSvfo8qdm7Y9KluB98tFCm7ASEy-g53RG5gY5P9kN3Br5ry24xM-tbgUNm8b3kaGQPYIC8F1UR63GvnbWM3YlkcvEs1CLtx6NA67klitn-kGfgZeGYKxOvB3vR1BLEmx-WBmSTdmGbGzYF_o.chNE7xDDBncS3_RPFq036Q)

How can I fix this? Is anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: Is anyone facing the same issue? what can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was cause by TCPresenceEvent which they have fixed on the latest update 1.2.3 released on March 19th. Installing this new updated library solved the issue for me hopefully it helps you as well.

[Twilio SDK iOS Changlog](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/ios/changelog)